# Reading CSV file with Hebrew content

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm trying to read CSV file with Hebrew content and I'm getting gibberish content.

When I open the file in Excel I see the Hebrew content correctly.

```js
function loadDoc() {
  readTextFile(function(csv) {
    data = csv
    console.log(data);
  });
}

function readTextFile(callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      callback(this.responseText)
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "./MyFile.csv", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What does your CSV look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the outdated `XMLHttpRequest` with a `fetch` call and use `async`/`await` to asynchronously load the file and get the content.

The callback paradigm has been superseded by `Promise` and `async`/`await`.

```js
const loadText = async (filename) => {
  const file = await fetch(filename);
  const text = await file.text();
  return text;
};

const main = async () => {
  const csvText = await loadText("./MyFile.csv");
  console.log(csvText);
};

main();
```

---

You can load the CSV as JSON using [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const loadText = async (filename) => {
  const file = await fetch(filename);
  const text = await file.text();
  return text;
};

const loadCsvAsJson = async (filename) => {
  const text = await loadText(filename);
  return Papa.parse(text);
};

const main = async () => {
  const jsonData = await loadCsvAsJson("../public/MyFile.csv");
  console.log(jsonData);
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The first solution is still giving me a gibberish result. 
 .... 16089,����,"[1,1]",�� �����,��� ,�����,����,����,0,0.00%,0,2,0,2,0,4 1 .... 
And with the second solution I'm getting some these errors :
(index):53 Error: multipleDefine
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Papa is not defined
I took exactly your code

Comment: @רחלבןצור You need to include Papa Parse library. If this is in a web page, use the CDN link, else you need to `import Papa from 'papaparse'` if running in Node.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I'll try in another way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be encoding of the html document where this JS script runs.

It can also be response headers of the server serving the CSV.

You should post screenshot of how gibberish looks like, or post a fiddle with file example. The problem may be with the file encoding as well: Excel can detect any encoding, but for JS you have to either prepare the file correctly, or transcode the contents on client side.

Comment: the gibberish looks like : 
.... 16089,����,"[1,1]",�� �����,��� ,�����,����,����,0,0.00%,0,2,0,2,0,4
1  ....

Comment: Most probable is the encoding of HTML page where you run this script. It should be UTF-8. Make a JS fiddle with the use case, then it will be very easy to identify.

Comment: If the encoding of page is correct. then try is to check if you have proper BOM sequence in the CSV. You can check this easily by creating a text file manually in Notepad or such, and save the file as UTF-8, and try it with your script. If it will work correctly, then that menas that the producer for CSV does not create files correctly (missing BOM mark. probably)

Comment: Thank you for answers. I'll try in another way.